# Is this a correct prepostition?

Tags: grammar

The theme of transformation is a common theme ''between''  the two dramas.

The theme of transforamtion is a common theme in the two dramas.

Comment: "Transformation is a common theme in the two dramas" would be correct. "Between" would be used more for comparison; e.g., "Between the two dramas, the first is better written." "Theme" does not need to be mentioned twice in your example. (Please click on the "?" in the upper right corner and take the "Tour" for more information about this site. Welcome to ELL!)

Answer (score 1):

Both *between* and *in* are fine, as is *of*.  Although I agree with Mark Hubbard that *between* implies comparison, many native speakers use it to group items.  Also, as Mark Hubbard mentions, *theme* doesn't need to be repeated.

> Transformation is a common theme **in** the two dramas.
>
> Transformation is a common theme **between** the two dramas.
>
> Transformation is a common theme **of** the two dramas.

You can, of course, reverse the order of the sentence to make it a moot point:

> The two dramas **have** the common theme of transformation.